# How do I set the default indentation settings for Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I'm using Sublime Text 3, I've set the default indentation settings per the [doc](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/1/indentation#).

[image]

However, when I relaunch the app, the default tab size is still 4 spaces. How do I do?

[image]

Here is the settings

```
{
"translateTabsToSpaces": true,
"tabSize": 2,
"detect_indentation":true, // I've also tried set this item as false, neither works.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the current documentation at https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/indentation.html:

```
{
    "tab_size": 2
}
```

Then save the User/Preferences.sublime-settings file and the change will take effect instantly.

Or change the Indentation setting under the View menu.

Comment: Thank you. Did you successfully change the setting yourself with this method?

Comment: @JJJohn Yes, I tested it.